# 'function' object has no attribute 'push'

Tags: python, stack, queue

```
import Queue_PlistLR as queueList

class Stack_2Queues():

        def __init__(self, name, salary):
                self.items = []
                self.name = name
                self.salary = salary

        def isEmpty(self):
                return len(self.items) == 0        

        def push(self, e):
                self._data.append(e)

        def pop(self):
                if self.is_empty:
                        raiseEmpty("Stack is empty")
                return self._data.pop()
        def size(self):
                return len(self.items) 

        def to_String(self):
                str_i = ""
                for e in self.items:
                        str_i+=str(e)+" "
                return str_i.strip() 

        def length(self):

                return len()

        def enqueue(self, item):
                self.items.append(item)

        def dequeue(self):
                if self.isEmpty():
                        raise Empty('Queue is empty')
                return self.items.pop(0)        

        def employeeName(self):
                print("The employee is: ", self.name)

        def employeeSalary(self):

                print("Employees salary is", self.salary)        

s1 = Stack_2Queues(["Ash", "Jen", "Mike", "Zach"], [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000])

s1.employeeName()
s1.employeeSalary()

s1.employeeName.push("Earl")
s1.employeeSalary.push(55000)
```

I am trying to push new values to the queues employeeName and employeeSalary()
However I am faced with this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `s1.push("Earl")` - push is a method on your class, not on its name which you get by employeeName(). your class is a datacontainer, not an employee - the methods of employeename and salary make no sense to me...

Comment: `employeeName` is clearly a method of `Stack_2Queues` class. Same stands for `employeeSalary`. You even call those methods before you try to `push`.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1.employeeName.push("Earl")
s1.employeeSalary.push(55000)
```

This is calls of `push` on methods. What is the idea? You have `push/pop` methods on your class, start with calling `s1.push`

Btw, you should probably look into [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Comment: s1.push didn't work. So the idea is I need to create a stack using 2 queues, is what I presented wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> 'function' object has no attribute 'push'
>   ...
>   What am I doing wrong?

`employeeName` and `employeeSalary` are not queues, the are instance methods (functions) of your class.  They do not have a (callable) `push` attribute.  They do not contain anything, they do something, so you cannot add to them.